# OpenGL Shader recursive process pixel

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

I have an OpenGL ES program to deal with a picture. If I deal with the current pixel, I need to use a previous pixel value. But it is not the pixel value of master map. It is a previous pixel value which has been handled.

Is the recursion can do in fragment shader?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. What do you mean by "deal with a picture"? What are you trying to do, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Fragment shaders are applied in no fixed order and have no side effects on global state. So the question is what you consider to be a previous pixel.

If you're looking to write an algorithm that does something involving, say, a left-to-right top-to-bottom image scan then you'll need explicitly to sample all of the source pixels you need to produce the output. If it's a certain pixel plus the three to that pixel's left then you'll need explicitly to fetch that pixel plus the three to the left. An example algorithm would be Floyd–Steinberg dithering.

If you're talking about previous frames then you'd achieve that with ping pong buffering whereby you use render-to-texture and switch back and forth between one destination and another so that you can treat the previous frame as an input texture. An example application might be the sort of things music visualisers usually do, including the one in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL ES 2.0 specs provides no means to access previous pixel value.

However, some GPUs have vendor-specific extensions which allows to access current fragment value of framebuffer. The one I know is `NV_shader_framebuffer_fetch` (Apple has similar extension `APPLE_shader_framebuffer_fetch`). On *Tegra 2* you can fetch previous value of fragment in GLSL from read-only `gl_LastFragColor` variable. This feature is meant to be used for custom blending in fragment shader. But it's available only on *nVidia Tegra* GPUs.

More information on this extension here: https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/mobile/files/tegra_gles2_development.pdf